# Xming Display is very slow when using SSH

Tags: linux, openssh, xming

I am using SSH and Xming to run Simics simulator and connect to some Linux guest machine. I use x11 Tunneling. The x server seems to be very slow and I need to spend a long time to run a single command on the linux guest machine. Do you have any idea what might cause the problem? Is this the problem of ssh secure shell or the xming?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Traffic compression might solve your problem. Use `ssh -C`

Comment: I am using XMing in windows to connect to a Mint machine. I use XFCE (with the XMing command xfce4-session) When I open a command terminal in the session the commands run as fast as if it were a native desktop. It's not clear if you problem is the commands or the X display. The display itself is quite slow, with visible drawing of the screen. It sped up by about 50%, to almost acceptable, by using compression (which is a check box in the XMing configuration dialog for the session).

Comment: This did help in my case.

Comment: I see improvements for me.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Putty.

Putting `Blowfish` compression to the top of the list in `Connection/SSH/Cipher` node also helped a little bit.

Compression is enabled in `SSH` node.